# Check file empty or not

Tags: shell, awk, text-processing

I have file which does not have any data in it
Need to check below scenario and return file is empty otherwise not empty

```
if file contains no data but as only spaces return it as FILE is EMPTY 
if file contains no data but as only tabs   return it as FILE is EMPTY
if file contains no data but as only empty new line  return it as FILE is EMPTY
```

Does this below code will satisfy all my above cases ? or any best approach all in one go

```
if [ -s /d/dem.txt ]
then
    echo "FILE IS NOT EMPTY AS SOME DATA"
else
    echo "FILE IS EMPTY NOT DATA AVAILABLE"
fi
```

Comment: What should happen if file has spaces *and* tabs?

Comment: @codeholic24 : `-s` tests the file size and hence is agnostic to white space inside the file. You can not make a decision on the content of a file, unless you look into the file.

Comment: @Daweo  Basically i need to count number of records in file .. if file does not have any records but only space or empty line or tabs then it will count it as record that should not happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk` for this:

```sh
awk 'NF {exit 1}' file && echo "empty" || echo "not empty"
```

Condition `NF` will be true only if there is non-whitespace character in the file.

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: @codeholic24: I have this explanation in answer `Condition NF will be true only if there is non-whitespace character in the file`. `NF` represents number of fields in a line and condition `NF` will be true only if there are non-space characters in a line.

Comment: In all awk: `awk 'NF{exit r=1}END{print (r?"not ":"") "empty"}'`

Comment: @anubhava  i am checking will confirm you

Comment: @anubhava is their any way to store the status of awk command if fail return 1 or pass return 0 , i can see that the above command exit the code that i don't want , their are few more lines in my script which i want to execute on basis of the above status

Comment: Yes sure just do: `ret=$(awk 'NF {exit 1}' file)` then check value of `$ret`

Comment: @anubhava  let me check it should satisfy all above mentioned conditions doing test run with all set of files

Answer (score 4):

Your description is a bit unclear (what do you want to do with a file that contains spaces, tabs, and newlines?), but it sounds like you just want to know if the file contains any non-whitespace characters.  So:

```
 if grep -q '[^[:space:]]' "$file"; then
     printf "%s\n" "$file is not empty";
 else
     printf "%s\n" "$file contains only whitespace"
 fi
```

Comment: can you explain the code `grep -q` what it does

Comment: @codeholic24 `grep -q pattern file` checks to see if pattern exists in the file.  `-q` suppresses all output.  If the pattern is in the file, `grep` returns 0.  If not, `grep` returns 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you had run your code you would have realized that no, `-s` considers that files with spaces, tabs and/or new lines are not empty. I would do it like this:

```
myfile="some_file.txt"
T=$(sed -e 's/\s//g' "$i")
if [ -n "$T" ]; then
    echo "$i is NOT empty"
else
    echo "$i is empty"
fi
```

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: `sed` looks for any instance of a whitespace character (`\s`) and replaces it with nothing. Then it's stored in a variable (`T`), and `bash` checks that that variable is empty (`[ -n "$T" ]`).